# Insert Images into an existing google slides template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Here's my current code:

```js
var NAME = "My favorite images";
var deck = SlidesApp.openById("1DKsiDGX9wwRbgP9WH2IJL2- 
    b1u1Q6jjz0JbrrKd_Fl4 ");

    /**
      * Creates a single slide using the image from the given link;
      * used directly by foreach(), hence the parameters are fixed.
      *
      * @param {Date} link A String object representing an image URL
      * @param {Date} index The index into the array; unused (req'd by 
        forEach)
      */
    function addImageSlide(imageUrl, index) {
      var slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BODY);
      var image = slide.insertImage(imageUrl);
      var imgWidth = image.getWidth();
      var imgHeight = image.getHeight();
      var pageWidth = deck.getPageWidth();
      var pageHeight = deck.getPageHeight();
      var newX = pageWidth / 2. - imgWidth / 2.;
      var newY = pageHeight / 2. - imgHeight / 2.;
      image.setLeft(newX).setTop(newY);
    }

    /**
      * The driver application features an array of image URLs, setting 
        of the
      * main title & subtitle, and creation of individual slides for each 
        image.
      */
    function main() {
      var images = [
        "http://www.google.com/services/images/phone-animation- 
        results_2x.png ",
        "http://www.google.com/services/images/section-work-card- 
        img_2x.jpg ",
        "http://gsuite.google.com/img/icons/product-lockup.png",
        "http://gsuite.google.com/img/home-hero_2x.jpg"
      ];
      var [title, subtitle] = deck.getSlides()[0].getPageElements();
      title.asShape().getText().setText(NAME);
      subtitle.asShape().getText().setText("");
      images.forEach(addImageSlide);
    }
```

I keep getting the error Cannot find method `appendSlide((class))`. (line 12, file "Code") 
What changes should I make to be able to insert URLs of images so that they can be inserted into an existing google slides template?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/predefined-layout) there is no predefined layout called `SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BODY`. Hence you get that error. If you change the layout to blank, for instance, this code works fine.

Please modify this line 12, like so:

```
var slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BODY);
```

```
var slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);
```

Comment: Yea i found that works. However, I have custom layouts in the template I created. How do I use those layouts?